# Scale and n-measures

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Imagine any shape. Scaling the sides of this shape by a factor of $x$, scale the area by a factor of $x^2$ and the volume by a factor of $x^3$. It seems quite obvious to me, after thinking about it, that such a relationship holds for any n-measure, where it is $x^n$ (by n-measure, I mean a measure corresponding to the dimension, 1-measure is length, 2-measure is area, 3-measure is volume). I am sure that it has something to do with linear algebra but I can't think of a way to start such a proof. I thought of trying to make some mapping, which translates every shape into an n-dimensional cube, then it's almost trivial but I'm not sure whether that would work. Any help is welcome!

Comment: I think that you could break every object with sides (not arcs) into triangular objects (could be multi-dimensional) and then extrapolate from the triangular object properties.

Comment: Good idea, I think arcs will also work like that with the help of calculus. I will try, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The linear transformation that scales an object by a number $c>0$ in all $n$ components can be represented by the matrix $cI$, where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix. The determinant of this matrix tells us what happens to the $n$-dimensional measure when the scaling is applied. Since this matrix is diagonal, its determinant is given by the product of the diagonal elements, $$\det(cI)= \prod_{i=1}^n c = c^n.$$